# Calling a method of abstract class from a concrete class without extending

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Example abstract class is bellow.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    void maintain(String str) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Example concrete class is bellow.

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
}
```

Now I need to access the maintain method without extending the Vehicle class.Is there any way to do this without using static content?

Comment: *"Now I need to access the maintain method without extending the Vehicle class"* Why? This smells like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It makes no sense to try to call an instance method without an instance, and you can't create an instance of an abstract class. You can only create a subclass instance.

Comment: `Vehicle vehicle =  new Driver();`???

Comment: Agree with "X/Y problem."  Looks like you should have a specific type of Vehicle for Driver to use.  The assignment is weird, a "driver" is not usually a type of "vehicle," so I think you've got something mixed up in your mind.

Comment: Yes, I agree that driver does not relate to the vehicle. But can we have any situations which require a specific method of the vehicle by the driver?

Comment: @ChamodPathirana: You simply can't do that in Java as you can in some other languages.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks, Now I got it.

Comment: If the question is about visibility modifiers than methods without any modifiers are accessible only from the same package. So to be able to access `Vechicle.maintain()` from `Driver` both `Vechicle` and `Driver` classes should be in one package.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, because `maintain` is an *instance method*. To call an instance method, you must have an instance. You can't create an instance of an abstract class.

You can subclass it anonymously (see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)), but you still need to subclass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `anonymous inner class`. I've used your example code but also defined an anstract method in `Vehicle`

```
public class AbstractTest {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle() {
            @Override
            void myOtherAbstractMethod() {
                // Do what you need here
            }
        };
        v.maintain("foo");
    }

    public static abstract class Vehicle {

        void maintain(String str) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        abstract void myOtherAbstractMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: If abstract classes can not be instantiated, how to do that here.
 Vehicle v = new Vehicle()

Comment: Because the `new Vehicle(){...}` is also an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as abstract classes are **abstract**. Also in your case there's no connection between `Driver` and `Vehicle` so even if you would be able to compile that code (you won't), then `ClassCastException` would show up.
You must extend abstract class first, like it or not.